# Debugging ES6 Node.js application with babel-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have some `jest` tests for my application. Other `js` sources which are used by the tests are written in `js ES6` with Flow. My goal is to debug the sources used by tests. When I debug them, however, the code is in transpiled/minified form.

I tried the following:

- `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node debug ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand` but the files are still minified (I have `.babelrc` with `es2015` and `stage-3` presets)
- `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --debug ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --runInBand` but it hangs after launching `jest`
- `babel-node-debug` sources displayed correctly but terminates before debugging (error described [here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/864))
- `babel-node` with presets on the command line but it thought presets were modules (`Error: Cannot find module *path*/es2015,stage-3`, similar error with space between them)
- `node-inspector` with `babel-node debug`. Shows sources correctly but it won't let me debug (the same error as above).
- `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./node_modules/bugger/bin/bugger.js -b ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --runInBand` (using `bugger` and `babel-node` - hangs after launching `jest`

#### My assumption

`babel-node` does generate appropriate source maps but command line debugger cannot read them and GUI tools somehow don't work. How to verify it?

#### My environment:

`Node v6.0.0
jest v12.0.2 (dev dependency)
babel 5.8.38 (babel-core 5.8.38) (dev dependency)`

#### Desired results

I would ultimately like to debug my files in chrome dev tools, but I wouldn't complain about the command line debugger.

I'm hesitant about installing yet more magic tools I don't know how to use, but I would be delighted to know why if I have to.

---

I'm new to the whole js stack so forgive me my silly questions!

Comment: Have you tried enabling source maps in babel (or the tool launching it)? Those work pretty well with recent version of the Chrome debugger, including resolving variable names.

Comment: @ssube how do I do that?

Comment: You should specify `sourceMaps` in your `.babelrc`. I would suggest setting them to `inline` for simplicity.

Comment: I did set it now, but I still cannot launch a UI debugger. Is my assumption about command line debugger correct?

Comment: yes, atm cli debugger does not make use of sourcemaps. Yo can try to connect chrome directly, I thisnk as of version v6.3.0 node can understand CRD protocol in addition to V8 debugger protocol - see https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js